# Laptop not going to sleep when closing the lid

Tags: laptop

Hi I installed Ubuntu on this laptop. It's an HP notebook. After I close the lid it just shuts off the screen and stays on. It is set to suspend when the lid is closed but nothing happens. Everything is updated. Any help?

Specs:
[image: Specs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, try manually suspending it first, to see what's up:

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

Suspend and hybernate have issues in 16.04 LTS at default kernel. Type uname -r to see which kernel you're using, probably 4.4.0.21 or 22. Doesn't work at this kernel with some laptops. Upgrading to a newer kernel from 4.4.8 onwards fixes the problem.

See more here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302

To upgrade the kernel, check here:
http://lifepluslinux.blogspot.hr/2016/04/ubuntu-1604-wont-wake-up-from-suspend.html

Comment: Right after I typed that the laptop just froze so i had to hold down the power button so it would power off then I just powered it back on.

Comment: I'm using 4.4.0-22-generic but ill check out how to upgrade the kernel